# HAML Error - 2 spaces were used for indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Use a HAML and partition in the site

show.html.haml

```
%ul
  =render :partial => "layouts/brand", :collection => @main_foreign_brands, :as => :brand
```

layouts/_brand.html.haml

```
%li=link_to brand.name, brand.url
```

but I have an error:
 Showing /my_site/app/views/mains/show.html.haml where line #11 raised:

Inconsistent indentation: 2 spaces were used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 4 spaces.

What's wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

%ul= render :partial => "layouts/brand", :collection => @main_russian_brands, :as => :brand

It's work

Comment: It works because you removed the indentation that was causing the problem, but you did not understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have the output: <ul> <li>brand1</li><li>brand2</li></ul>.  I use the Aptana, and I think that the problem in the editor

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure that you do not mix tabs and spaces for indentation.
This can happen if you change editor configurations, or if you paste text from other sources. Many editors offer a command that converts spaces to tabs and vice versa. Try to find it in your editor.

In Sublime Text 2 you would do it using the indentation menu in the lower right corner, it has options that say: "Convert indentation to spaces" and "Convert indentation to tabs".

Answer (score 1):

Jesper's answer is enough for you to fix your code. If you still have problem with this, you [can use this link](http://html2haml.heroku.com/) to convert html to haml. Use sublime2 or notepad++ when working with haml:)